# Elasticsearch java api create too many thread

Tags: java, elasticsearch

We have a simple webapp that is sending a lot of data to our elasticsearch node.

This is how we create the transport client to elasticsearch

```
        TransportClient client = new TransportClient().addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(elasticSearchUrl, 9300));
```

Everythings go fine and the data is going though until something happens to the elasticsearch node. So, if we shutdown the cluster we get a very nice expected exception

```
org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: No node available
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$RetryListener.onFailure(TransportClientNodesService.java:249)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:217)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.support.InternalTransportClient.execute(InternalTransportClient.java:106)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.index(AbstractClient.java:84)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.index(TransportClient.java:316)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexRequestBuilder.doExecute(IndexRequestBuilder.java:324)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:85)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:59)
    at com.startmobi.statistics.core.StatisticServiceManager.createStatistic(StatisticServiceManager.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor382.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocationTraceInterceptor.invoke(RemoteInvocationTraceInterceptor.java:77)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy178.createStatistic(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor381.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocation.invoke(RemoteInvocation.java:205)
    at org.springframework.remoting.support.DefaultRemoteInvocationExecutor.invoke(DefaultRemoteInvocationExecutor.java:38)
    at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocationBasedExporter.invoke(RemoteInvocationBasedExporter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocationBasedExporter.invokeAndCreateResult(RemoteInvocationBasedExporter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerServiceExporter.handleRequest(HttpInvokerServiceExporter.java:73)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:49)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at com.googlecode.psiprobe.Tomcat60AgentValve.invoke(Tomcat60AgentValve.java:30)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:291)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

The problem is, 10 seconds later we get another exception

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:640)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addThread(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:681)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addIfUnderMaximumPoolSize(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:727)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:655)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.sendRequest(TransportService.java:203)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.TransportActionNodeProxy.execute(TransportActionNodeProxy.java:68)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.support.InternalTransportClient$2.doWithNode(InternalTransportClient.java:109)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:214)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.support.InternalTransportClient.execute(InternalTransportClient.java:106)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.index(AbstractClient.java:84)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.index(TransportClient.java:316)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexRequestBuilder.doExecute(IndexRequestBuilder.java:324)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:85)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:59)
    at com.startmobi.statistics.core.StatisticServiceManager.createStatistic(StatisticServiceManager.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor382.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocationTraceInterceptor.invoke(RemoteInvocationTraceInterceptor.java:77)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy178.createStatistic(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor381.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocation.invoke(RemoteInvocation.java:205)
    at org.springframework.remoting.support.DefaultRemoteInvocationExecutor.invoke(DefaultRemoteInvocationExecutor.java:38)
    at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocationBasedExporter.invoke(RemoteInvocationBasedExporter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocationBasedExporter.invokeAndCreateResult(RemoteInvocationBasedExporter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerServiceExporter.handleRequest(HttpInvokerServiceExporter.java:73)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:49)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at com.googlecode.psiprobe.Tomcat60AgentValve.invoke(Tomcat60AgentValve.java:30)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:291)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

And the whole operation system just get super busy and we have to restart the whole machine. Do you guys have any clue what the problem can be?

EDIT: We are using ES version 0.9.12

Comment: Which version of Elasticsearch is this?

Comment: Have you tried opening up your application in Visual VM (or another profiler) to see its memory usage and therefore _what_ is to blame for the `OutOfMemoryError`? It's possible that it's the thread count, but the executor should not be creating more threads than the `Executor` supports, which makes this look like it is a symptom of another issue. Specifically, the block that is failing is within a `catch (Throwable)` that is probably catching the `OutOfMemoryError` itself, then retriggering it.

Comment: We are using ES 0.9.12. I will try the profile tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were using elasticsearch 0.90.12 and the java library was 0.90.6. Since we updated the java library to 0.90.12 all the problem disappeared.